# passing Java object to another JSP

Tags: java, jsp

is there any way that i can declare an instance of a Java Object in one JSP file, and call this instance in another JSP file?

for example:
in 1.jsp:

```
<%
  Obj o = new Obj();
%>
```

and in 2.jsp:

```
<@%include file = "1.jsp">
<%
  o.toString();
%>
```

(of course, the above example does not work. it's just to clearify what i was talking about).

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing list/array between JSP pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614239/passing-list-array-between-jsp-pages)

Answer (score 5):

You can put your object as request attribute:

```
Obj o= new Obj();
request.setAttribute("myCreatedObject" , o );

...

Obj myObj = (Obj)request.getAttribute("myCreatedObject");
```

Consider another contexts than request like session, page - it's like variable scope.

Comment: Agree +1. And the `request.setAttribute` is usually used in compination with `requestDispatcher.forward()`. I would recommend the `session` variable scope as it is easier to use (at least in the beggining levels of learning jsp/servlets)

Answer (score 0):

You should defining the java object as Bean in JSP. 
The Bean in JSP can be defined using :- 
< jsp:useBean..> standard jsp tag. 
And set and get property using < jsp:setProperty..> and < jsp:getProperty..> standard jsp tags.And then you can use the Object as well as share between jsp pages.